# How to dissmiss the add Annotation Animation of a MKAnnotation?

Tags: animation, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I need to add a big number of annotations on a MKMapview and, the animation which give the impression that the pin falls on the map make that take lot of time to display all of them.

Anyone can help me ?

Sorry for my english ! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable dropping animation with `animatesDrop` attribute

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

MKAnnotationView *annView =[[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation"] autorelease];


        annView.animatesDrop=FALSE;
}
```